# publish an npm package

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm an absolutly newbie creating npm packages using typescript2 and angular2. Nevertheless, I need to create an npm package and publish it on our private repository.

I've been able to generate `d.ts` and `.js` files. What do I need to do in order to pack the package and publish to my npm repository?

[Here](https://github.com/jeusdi/swagger-client), you can find the repository.

Also, I've been able to login successfully on my private npm registry:

```
#npm --registry http://private.npm-registry.com/npm/npm_unstable login
```

So, I know I need to perform something like `npm publish` but I don't know which's the content of the package (the content of `./dist` folder)?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers), I found some guide is talking about npm development.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NPMTS https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmts

In the most basic scenario you want to use the files array of your package.json to just publish the dist folder.

Regards